# use the excel vba workbook deactivate event

Tags: excel, vba, events

I'am trying to prevent users from pasting other things than values in the template I'm developing. I use a macro to always paste values in the worksheet (see below). When users switch to another workbook this macro should be disabled.
The problem is that I get error 91 when activating another workbook.

'the macro in a module

```
Sub AlwaysPasteValues()
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

'the code in this workbook

```
Public wb As Workbook

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
  Application.MacroOptions Macro:="AlwaysPasteValues", Description:="AlwaysPasteValues", ShortcutKey:="v"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
  With wb
    .MacroOptions Macro:="AlwaysPasteValues", Description:="AlwaysPasteValues", ShortcutKey:=""
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so perhaps you could explain what you exactly are concerned about with users pasting stuff in the template?  This does not seem like the best approach IMO.  If you are concerned about what values are entered into fields you can always use data validation on those cells.

Comment: This also only takes care of the case where someone uses CTRL+V to paste.  If I use the normal menus to paste formulas, this code will not stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing `.MacroOptions` on `wb` which does not exist as a property.  `MacroOptions` is for the `Application`.  Use the same code as the `Activate` and you should be good.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="AlwaysPasteValues", Description:="AlwaysPasteValues", ShortcutKey:=""

End Sub
```